# Android Layout Editor Error (Cannot Create Constraint on Editor): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Collection is empty

Tags: android-studio, android-support-library

I got an error on Android Studio (3.3.2) Layout Editor.

It was so sudden, before, the error was never exist, I don't know why.

[image]

This error was prevent me to create constraint using visual editor.
I have to define constraint using code by my self, and it was painful for me.

Please help how to solve this problem.

What I have done:

1. Reinstall Android SDK
2. Invalidate cache and Restart
3. Uninstall all beta version of the SDK.

Comment: remove .AndroidStudio and .cache folder in your user folder.

Comment: @HyperMax1991 I cannot find any .cache folder in my user folder.

Comment: @HyperMax1991 I have delete those folder, but the error still appear.

Comment: I've the same problem and currently I solved downgrading to 2.0.0-alpha03. I've opened a ticket here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131206380

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. It is a problem with the Contraint Layout dependency. In the build.gradle of my project, I was using

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
```

Then, I just downgraded it to

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

and the error was solved. I guess that we'll have to wait for a fixed version.

Comment: I have done that, and I have invalidate cache and restart. But the problem still appear. :(

Comment: I fixed this by downgraded to version 1.1.3 of Contsraint layout.

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'

to

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved in [ConstraintLayout 2.0.0-alpha05](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/04/constraintlayout-200-alpha-5.html) as described [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130073708#comment8)  by a Google engineer